# WordPress Database Backup Question

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-restore

I am working on a charity site and was tasked with moving a WordPress site to another host from Yahoo hosting. I have done this before and thought it would be easy enough.

Before moving the site I backed up all the files and backed up the database. The files are fine, but the database backup has me stumped.

I ended up with the following file: mysqldata.2009-09-20-18-37.tar.gz

I thought I was in good shape and could just import the file using PHPmyAdmin, however, when I unzipped the file it is not a sql file at all but has the following structure:

blog
mysql

Within the mysql director it has a list of files like this:

user.MYI
columns_priv.frm
columns_priv.MYD
columns_priv.MYI
db.frm
db.MYD
db.MYI
func.frm
func.MYD
func.MYI
host.frm
host.MYD
host.MYI
tables_priv.frm
tables_priv.MYD
tables_priv.MYI
user.frm
user.MYD

Is there some way I can restore the database with the information in this form?

Thanks!

Comment: Retagged 'mysql'. Also I think this may belong better on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your new database server, create the new database, e.g. `CREATE DATABASE my_wordpress_blog`

Copy these `.MYI`, `.MYD` and `.frm` files to wherever MySQL stores the files for this database, e.g. `/var/lib/mysql/my_wordpress_blog/`

This will probably only work if the version of MySQL on your new server is the same or newer than your old server.

Comment: In some hosting situations, may have to get your host to put those files in the correct folder.

Comment: Ben, I think this is my best option and I will see if I can get access to those folders. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hy if you have shell acces to the server just do

```
`mysqldump  db_name backup-file.sql`
```

And restore the db in phpmyadmin.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to the server. Comment appreciated though.

Answer (score 1):

Might also consider using the WordPress Tools->Export at the old blog and Tools->Import->WordPress at the new blog.

Or installing a plugin that will create a backup you can restore from within phpMyAdmin.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-db-backup/

Comment: My biggest challenge is that I no longer have access to the old server. The account has been closed and I am trying to rebuild the site with what I have. :(